# Immediately invoked functions with constructors / Universal Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics, event-tracking

I'm trying to figure out how tracking / analytics scripts work. There's an optimised version of [the Google Analytics code](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet#universal-analytics):

```
<script>
  (function(window, document, variableName, scriptElement, firstScript) {
    window['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = variableName;
    window[variableName] || (window[variableName] = function() {
      (window[variableName].q = window[variableName].q || []).push(arguments);
    });
    window[variableName].l = +new Date;
    scriptElement = document.createElement('script'),
    firstScript = document.scripts[0];
    scriptElement.src = 'https://127.0.0.1:3000/analytics.js';
    firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, firstScript)
  }(window, document, 'ga'));

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Loading a custom script, I can't figure out how the ga() functions work. I tried various IIFE and constructors already, but don't get the 'create' and 'send' events.

How do I see these events on the server?

**update**

I managed to abstract my way to the queue, now wondering how I can create an async queue to send these events to the server. Any suggestions?

```
(function() {
  var ga = function(a) {
    return void 0 != a && -1 < (a.constructor + '').indexOf('String');
  };
  var sa = function(a) {
    return a ? a.replace(/^[\s\xa0]+|[\s\xa0]+$/g, '') : '';
  };
  var gb = ga(window.GoogleAnalyticsObject) && sa(window.GoogleAnalyticsObject) || 'ga';
  var Window = window;
  var Document = document;

  console.log(Window[gb].q);

})(window);
```

Comment: Where's *your* code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is merely pushing all the calls arguments into an array. It's later picked up by the `analytics.js` through `window.GoogleAnalyticsObject`. Google doesn't seem to provide a non-minified version of `analytics.js` but a quick debeautify and a search you end up with:

```
var gb = qa(window.GoogleAnalyticsObject) && sa(window.GoogleAnalyticsObject) || "ga"
```

The `qa` checks if it's a String and the `sa` function just clears the name a little bit.

So, where else do they use `gb`? Assignments only happen somewhere else:

The `N.N` function:

```
N.N = function() {
        "ga" != gb && J(49);
        var a = O[gb];
        if (!a || 42 != a.answer) {
            N.L = a && a.l;
            N.loaded = !0;
            var b = O[gb] = N;
            X("create", b, b.create);
            X("remove", b, b.remove);
            X("getByName", b, b.j, 5);
            X("getAll", b, b.getAll, 6);
            b = pc.prototype;
            X("get", b, b.get, 7);
            X("set", b, b.set, 4);
            X("send", b, b.send);
            b = Ya.prototype;
            X("get", b, b.get);
            X("set", b, b.set);
            if (!Ud() && !Ba) {
                a: {
                    for (var b = M.getElementsByTagName("script"), c = 0; c < b.length && 100 > c; c++) {
                        var d = b[c].src;
                        if (d && 0 == d.indexOf("https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics")) {
                            J(33);
                            b = !0;
                            break a
                        }
                    }
                    b = !1
                }
                b && (Ba = !0)
            }
            Ud() || Ba || !Ed(new Od) || (J(36), Ba = !0);
            (O.gaplugins = O.gaplugins || {}).Linker = Dc;
            b = Dc.prototype;
            Yd.set("linker", Dc);
            X("decorate", b, b.ca, 20);
            X("autoLink", b, b.S, 25);
            Yd.set("displayfeatures", fd);
            Yd.set("adfeatures", fd);
            a = a && a.q;
            ka(a) ? Z.D.apply(N, a) : J(50)
        }
    };
```

Assignment happens on:

```
var a = O[gb]; //O is window
```

The `ga` function you are using on your script, will soon be replaced by something else (`N`):

```
var b = O[gb] = N;
```

Here's N:

```
var N = function(a) {
        J(1);
        Z.D.apply(Z, [arguments])
    };
```

Where is the queue being used?

```
a = a && a.q;
ka(a) ? Z.D.apply(N, a) : J(50)
```

The `Z.D` function seems the one that's executing your arguments. Which uses more minified functions. I suggest you keep looking from here.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Google Analytics is quite a chunk to go through. Managed to abstract some code, but still stuck.